# can I remove 12.0 from After Effects CC? (It takes 8GB!)

Tags: adobe-after-effects

> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\Adobe\After Effects>

has two directories.

12.0

and

12.1

12.0 takes 8GB

12.1 takes 4GB

Can I remove 12.0?

How about 12.1 also?

Each one has this big directory within it

> C:\Users\harvey\AppData\Local\Temp\Adobe\After Effects\12.0\Disk Cache
>   - compname.noindex

Comment: Welcome to GD.  At this time this seems to be off-topic because it is tech support and that is off-topic on GD.  I would suggest, if you would like, migrating this question to Super User or asking Adobe's tech support forum.

Comment: @Matt I can't migrate it. I see no option. Can you migrate it to superuser?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course you can.
This is a temporary folder, that allows you load previous Ram Previews.
But don´t worry, because AE CC it´ll create this folder again. I repeat, it´s just a temporary folder from your Ram Previews.